# Changing NALU h.264/avc, for RTP encupsulation

Tags: udp, video-streaming, h.264, rtp, rfc

What I can and cant change in NALU in terms of syntex and size, if the nal is meant for RTP encupsulation?

Comment: what you want to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change whatever you want, provided that resulting bit stream is still compliant to:

- MPEG-4 Part 10 Specification (H.264)
- RTP RFCs 3550 (RTP), 3984 (RTP Payload for H.264)